# Django Crispy Forms and Option Groups

Tags: django, django-crispy-forms, optgroup

I've been searching around on the Crispy Forms documentation as well as general web searching for an answer to this.

Can Crispy Forms output `<optgroup>`'s within a ChoiceField using the forms.Select widget? Or must I take the data into the context and build the form out the old fashioned way in the template?

Thanks!

Comment: Please show some code. Have you grouped your choices [as in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#choices)?

Comment: Thank you. I got so hung up on looking for a solution in Crispy's documentation that I neglected checking the basic Django docs on it. I feel like an idiot.

(Still new to the Django world so forgive me.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
USER_GENERATED_TEMPLATES = MessageTemplate.objects.filter(Q(client=client_id) | Q(client=None) & Q(user_generated=True))
DEFAULT_TEMPLATES = MessageTemplate.objects.filter(Q(client=client_id) | Q(client=None) & Q(user_generated=False))

# Set the initial TEMPLATE CHOICES list to include the Default Templates choice object
TEMPLATE_CHOICES = [('Default Templates',([[template.id, template.name] for template in DEFAULT_TEMPLATES]))]

# If there are user generated templates, append the TEMPLATE_CHOICES list to include them
if USER_GENERATED_TEMPLATES.count() > 0:
    TEMPLATE_CHOICES.append(('Saved Templates',([[template.id, template.name] for template in USER_GENERATED_TEMPLATES])))

# Set the 'template' form field to a ChoiceField using the Select widget populated by the TEMPLATE_CHOICES list.
self.fields['template'] = forms.ChoiceField(widget = forms.Select(), choices=TEMPLATE_CHOICES)
```

Answer (score 6):

The [choices docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#choices) give an example of how you can group your choices.

```
MEDIA_CHOICES = (
    ('Audio', (
            ('vinyl', 'Vinyl'),
            ('cd', 'CD'),
        )
    ),
    ('Video', (
            ('vhs', 'VHS Tape'),
            ('dvd', 'DVD'),
        )
    ),
    ('unknown', 'Unknown'),
)
```

If you do this, then the select widget should output optgroups, whether or not you use crispy forms.

Comment: Thanks Alasdair, I was able to hit that up earlier and figure out what I needed. Posted it below for future reference.