# Split radio buttons in several groups with crispy-forms

Tags: django, django-templates, django-crispy-forms

I would like to create a django form to plan a meeting.

I have to propose several timeslots, and regroup them by day, like in the following image.

Is it possible to do that with crispy-forms, by using the same ChoiceField for all the radio buttons ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django does this already, but Crispy only does this if you are using the Bootstrap v4 template pack. (**Note:** I am referencing Crispy 1.x in my answer. Crispy 2 was just released a couple of weeks ago and has significant changes that I haven't reviewed yet, so my answer is only good for the 1.x version.)

If you look at the [Django docs for the `Field.choices` value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41550354/844976), it shows that you can use a structure like this:

```
from django import forms

CHOICES = [
    ('vendredi 17 fevrier 2023', (
        ('20230217_0900', 'De 09:00 a 09:00'),
        ('20230217_0920', 'De 09:20 a 09:40'),
    )),
    ('lundi 20 fevrier 2023', (
        ('20230220_1600', 'De 16:00 a 16:20'),
    ))
]

class MyForm(forms.Form):
    my_field = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.widgets.RadioSelect, choices=CHOICES)
```

And when used in a Django template (`{{ form }}`), the HTML is structured like you want:

```
<label for="id_my_field_0">My field:</label>
<ul id="id_my_field">
  <li>vendredi 17 fevrier 2023
    <ul id="id_my_field_0">
      <li>
        <label for="id_my_field_0_0"><input type="radio" name="my_field" value="20230217_0900" required="" id="id_my_field_0_0">
          De 09:00 a 09:00</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <label for="id_my_field_0_1"><input type="radio" name="my_field" value="20230217_0920" required="" id="id_my_field_0_1">
          De 09:20 a 09:40</label>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>lundi 20 fevrier 2023
    <ul id="id_my_field_1">
      <li>
        <label for="id_my_field_1_0"><input type="radio" name="my_field" value="20230220_1600" required="" id="id_my_field_1_0">
          De 16:00 a 16:20</label>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

But as for Crispy, it looks like it is only available if you are using their
Bootstrap v4 templates: https://github.com/django-crispy-forms/django-crispy-forms/blob/1.14.0/crispy_forms/templates/bootstrap4/layout/radioselect.html. Notice that they are looping over `optgroups` on line 6. They don't do this in the other template packs that they offer. And so if you are using one of those other template packs, then I think you need to write a custom widget/template. (I might have to investigate that a bit before being 100% sure, b/c there might be a way to do it in the `Form.__init__` method, where you can dynamically update fields and widgets and such.)

Anyhow, this might not solve your problem, but hopefully it points you in the right direction. Let me know if I can offer any more help!

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know optgroups. I don't use bootstrap 4 currently but I will try to render this without crispy forms